# How to get position().left/top of an element before setting it to absolute position?

Tags: jquery

I need to get the current position(top, left) of an element before I set it to absolute position .

doing this :

```
var left = $(element).position().left;
$(element).css({'position':'absolute'});
```

left will allways be 0 . But the initial position is not 0 . If i don't use the css() method to set absolute position , left is returning the right left position . Any ideea about how to resolve this issue ?

P.S. : Before answerng , this bug was also posted on jquery bug tracker. But noone answered there neither . Read carefully my question . I'm not asking how to get the position , I'm asking why do I get the same position for any set of elements [Jquery bug link](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/3037).  It's normal to get same position for all elements after you set them to absolute , not before . Or am I wrong ?

Comment: same issue . Getting same left position for all elements that are being positioned absolute

Comment: Is the element visible?

Comment: Yes m it is visible , they all are . And am getting same postion for all . If i don't set absolute position i get the good return

Comment: There must be something in the rest of your code. Here's a jsfiddle that does basically what I expect you are doing, and it works fine. Are you using a very old jQuery version or something? http://jsfiddle.net/3tF7h/5/

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to get it's css defined left position, use

```
var left = parseInt($element.css("left"));
```

If you're trying to get it's position relative to the document, use

```
var left = $element.offset().left;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.offset()` rather than `.position()`, which will give you the coordinates of the element based on the `document` element rather than the HTML parent (with a non-static position set).

Docs:

http://api.jquery.com/offset

http://api.jquery.com/position